# Replace outliers with NA

Tags: r, simulation, missing-data, outliers

I have found this function and I would like to adapt it to replace outliers with NA instead of removing the observation.

I have tried to add `<-NA` in this line `data <- data[!outliers(data[[col]]),]` but I cannot make it work. Could you help me to adapt it, please?

Here you can find the code with some simulated data. Please let me know if you need something else.

Thank you so much in advance.

```
cov.matone <- matrix(c(1, .0,
                       .0, 1), nrow = 2)

data <- data.frame(MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1e4, 
                                  mu = c(4, 4), 
                                  Sigma = cov.matone))

outliers <- function(x) {
  
  Q1 <- quantile(x, probs=.25, na.rm=T)
  Q3 <- quantile(x, probs=.75, na.rm=T)
  iqr = Q3-Q1
  
  upper_limit = Q3 + (iqr*1.5)
  lower_limit = Q1 - (iqr*1.5)
  
  x > upper_limit | x < lower_limit
}

remove_outliers <- function(data, cols = names(data)) {
  for (col in cols) {
    data <- data[!outliers(data[[col]]),]
  }
  data
}

data_nooutliers <- remove_outliers(data, c('X1', 'X2' ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning the loop results to the input data, use `is.na<-` to assign `NA` values to elements given by function `outliers`.

```
remove_outliers <- function(data, cols = names(data)) {
  for (col in cols) {
    is.na(data[[col]]) <- outliers(data[[col]])
  }
  data
}
```

---

### Note

The following function does exactly the same as function `outliers` but is a much simpler one-liner.

```
outliers2 <- function(x) x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out

s1 <- lapply(names(data), \(x) outliers(data[[x]]))
s2 <- lapply(names(data), \(x) outliers2(data[[x]]))
identical(s1, s2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @JuanJMV Thanks, glad to help. And see the edit with a simpler function `outliers`.